# Qt: Segfault при конвертации данных из QString в Double

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть таблица:

```
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < db.gList->Goods->size(); i++)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->insertRow(i);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 0 , new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 1 , new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(db.gList->Goods->at(i).GID))); //i, db.gList->Goods->at(i).gName, db.gList->Goods->at(i).gAmount, db.gList->Goods->at(i).gPrice
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 2 , new QTableWidgetItem(db.gList->Goods->at(i).gName));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 3 , new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(db.gList->Goods->at(i).gAmount)));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, 4 , new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(db.gList->Goods->at(i).gPrice)));
    }
```

Есть обработка клика по таблице в форме

```
    void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *item)
    {
        QString strText;
        int row = item->row();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); i++)
        {
            strText += ui->tableWidget->item(row, i)->text() + " ";
        }
        int _gsid;
        int _gAmount;
        double _gPrice;
        _gsid = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 1)->text().toInt();
        _gAmount = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 3)->text().toInt();
        _gPrice = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 4)->text().toDouble();

        db.bList->AddItem(_gsid, _gAmount, _gPrice);

      //  ui->listWidget_2->addItem(ui->tableWidget->item(row, 2)->text());
        //qDebug() << strText;
    }
```

Когда вызывается

```
_gPrice = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 4)->text().toDouble();
```

происходит сегфолт.

Что я делаю не так?
Как это исправить?
Какова механика процесса?

Comment: Проверьте, что ваше `ui->tableWidget->item(row, 4)` не возвращает `nullptr`, а то очень похоже на то

Comment: @BeardedBeaver да. Возвращается nullptr. Нашёл ошибку!

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я объявил всего 4 столбца таблицы в её инициализации. `ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);` 
Когда я сменил число на 5 всё заработало и проверочное условие 
`if (ui->tableWidget->item(row, 4)) qDebug() << "nullptr returned";` перестало кидаться сообщением в итоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ до безобразия прост.
было объявлено 4 столбца в таблице

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);
```

Но я использовал их 5, это следует в цикле, сразу за этой строкой. 
Далее я пытаюсь обратиться к 5ому столбцу

```
_gPrice = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 4)->text().toDouble();
```

, но столбцов всего 4.
[image: Иллюстрация данных в таблице]
 Отсюда получается что при попытке обращения  я получаю сегфолт ибо возвращается nullptr.